# Q: htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently i have this in my .htaccess

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite user URLs
RewriteRule ^index/^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?index=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?index=$1
```

In my browser, when i access like this :

http://domain.com/aboutus

It is working as expected. What i'm trying to do is, how if i have something like this :

http://domain.com/category/sports

What should i put in my .htaccess so that it can read the URL format for the main-category and subcategory ?

Comment: I don't think you provided enough information. Are your categories/subcategories dynamic? And is there a query string for subcategories?

Comment: i'm sorry for the lack of information. Yes, the main category and subcategories will be dynamic @PanamaJack . There is no query string in subcategories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out the forward slash in your regex.

```
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z-\/]+)$ index.php?index=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-\/]+)$ index.php?index=$1 [L]
```

Even better, combine the rules into one:

```
RewriteRule ^(index/)?([0-9a-zA-Z-\/]+)$ index.php?index=$2 [L]
```

Also added the `[L]` flag to stop rewriting when a match is found.

Comment: I try use your way, the rule is correct i think. But how do i read from the URL? i use $_GET['index'] to fetch the URL . If i have main category and sub-category which is dynamic, the output will be category/subcategory. How do i i split so that the data that i get from the URL is more readable for programming purpose?

Comment: If you are passing the request URI to `index`, then you need to use PHP to interpret the request. You can start with [`explode('/', $_GET['index']);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention i able to do it so. i insert the value into array and explode it for dynamic function purpose.Thanks !